# Android left to right swipe only

Tags: android, swipe, swipe-gesture, onfling

I am a beginner in Android. I need to **swipe only from left to right** and to **do not swipe from right to left**. For this what I want to do? All the examples are showing both left to right and right to left?

Comment: What do you want to happen when you swipe ? Maybe you can post some of the examples you found and explain what you want to do differently...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10008053/android-trouble-with-swipe-gesture is an example which i referred. In that example also they are doing both direction swipe. I need only from left to right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the accepted solution here - [Fling gesture detection on grid layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection)

The solution explains how to implement a simple gesture listener, and record left to right and  right to left swipes. The relevant code from the example is in the GestureDetector `onFling` override method. Basically, if point 1 (e1) minus point 2 (e2) is greater than a set minimum swipe distance, then you know it's right to left. If point 2 (e2) minus point 1 (e1) was greater than the minimum swipe distance then it's left to right.

```
// right to left swipe
if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
    Toast.makeText(SelectFilterActivity.this, "Left Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}  
// left to right swipe
else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
     Toast.makeText(SelectFilterActivity.this, "Right Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Kyle, Thanks for your detailed answer. Now I understood about this.

Answer (score 1):

You can Use `Drag and Drop` 
You can Study this tutorial this is very nice tutorial

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html

aur you can  have alook to

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html

Comment: This example is only about the drag and drop. I need to do the swipe operation from left to right. Please help me on that.