# Trying to get OnFling to work

Tags: android, swipe, touch-event, uiswipegesturerecognizer, swipe-gesture

I know there are plenty of questions regarding this topic. I've had a look at most of them, but still I'm not able to debug my code. It does not detect swipes. I'm a beginner to both Android programming as well as Java, so please don't be too critical.

- I have a simple Linear Layout, with a Button that fills the whole layout. Everytime the button is clicked, it's value increments by 1.
- I'm trying to implement left on right swipes. My basic doubt is should I implement the setOnTouchListener with the Button or the Linear Layout?
- I've seen people use OnGestureListener and OnTouchListener. Which one is preferable?

  ```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

  public Button increment;
  public int cnt= 0;
  private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 80;
  private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 40;
  GestureDetector gestureDetector;
  LinearLayout swipe_layout= (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear);

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      increment= (Button)findViewById(R.id.numberkey);
      increment.setOnClickListener(this);
      setDisplay(0);
      gestureDetector= new GestureDetector(this, new Detector());
      increment.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

          @Override
          public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
              gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
              return true;
          }
      });

  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) 
  {
      setDisplay(cnt++);
  }

  private void setDisplay(int i) 
  {   increment.setText(String.valueOf(i));
  }

  class Detector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

  @Override
      public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
          return true;
      }


      @Override
      public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float            velocityY) {
              // right to left swipe
              if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY)
                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Left Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

              else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Right Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
          return false;
      }

  }
  ```

  }

Thanks in advance.

Comment: But should I call onTouchListener with the layout instead of the button? the button fills the whole layout.

Comment: yes you can call it with layout

Answer (score 0):

move

```
LinearLayout swipe_layout= (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear);
```

after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` of Activity because you are trying to find view before setting layout for current Activity

and set `onTouchListener` for Layout as :

```
LinearLayout swipe_layout;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    swipe_layout= (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear);

    swipe_layout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

     @Override
       public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

         return true;
    }
  });
```

Comment: Still, the swipes don't work, the toasts don't appear. It takes my swipe gestures as simply clicks. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @Chocolava : see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10008053/android-trouble-with-swipe-gesture) post

Comment: No, it's not, I tried everything that guy did. Specifically, could you please tell me whether we should return true or false from the onTouch method?

Comment: Because in that thread, the code that guy wrote, he returned false from the method.

Comment: @Chocolava : yes you can also  return false from  onTouch. have u tried aneal answer in given thread

Comment: Yes, I did try aneal's answer. The exception is never caught, so probably the method does not reach onFling. Returning true or false from onTouch has no meaning? It can be either?